# Console calculator program in C++ not working correctly

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm kind of new to programming in C++, and after a bit of learning how it works, I tried making this console calculator application, which takes in two numbers from the user x and y, and then adds, subtracts, multiplies or divides the two numbers depending on the third z input. I'm using code blocks as the IDE, and the code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

//First input value
int x;
//Second input value;
int y;
//Operator value;
int z;
int main()
{
    //Asks user for first number
    std::cout << "Input first number" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "" << std::endl;

    //Asks user for second number
    std::cout << "Input second number" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> y;
    std::cout << "" << std::endl;

    //Asks user for operation
    std::cout << "Input operation: 1 for add, 2 for sub, 3 for multiply, 4 for divide" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> z;

    //Displaying the desired output
    if (z = 1)
    {
        std::cout << x + y << std::endl;
    }
    else if (z = 2)
    {
        std::cout << x - y << std::endl;
    }
    else if (z = 3)
    {
        std::cout << x * y << std::endl;
    }
    else (z = 4);
    {
        std::cout << x / y << std::endl;
    }

    //Just a stupid comment
    std::cout << "Thank you for using this piece of shit xD. Press any key to end" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Even though it compiles without any errors, every operation input seems to add the numbers together rather than the desired operation. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `if (z = 1)` -- See anything wrong with that line and others similar to it?  How are comparisons for equality done in C++?

Comment: Add `-Wall -pedantic -Werror` to the compilation flags.

Comment: Your check conditions are wrong. eg `if (z = 1)` etc. This becomes an assignment operation and `z` will be assigned the value of 1. The correct way to check variable values is by using `==`, eg `if (z == 1)`

Comment: `else (z = 4);` -- Another syntax issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are just assigning the value in 'Z' variable (Z=1, Z=2..) in "if and else if" condition, That is wrong for checking the values. However, in this case you can use switch case. Like as below.

```
switch(z){
    case 1:
    std::cout << x + y << std::endl;
    break;
    case 2:
    std::cout << x - y << std::endl;
    break;
    case 3:
    std::cout << x * y << std::endl;
    break;
    case 4:
    std::cout << x / y << std::endl;
    break;
    default:
    std::cout << "select proper option" << std::endl;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if else conditions are wrong, you are using assignment operator (=) instead of equalto (==) comparison operator.

Do if(z=1) --> if(z==1) an same for remaining else conditions.

Note that the division will return an integer rounded value, hence it's preferable to cast your numerator to double before division.

Just do x/y --> (x*1.0)/y

Comment: Note that in division it will return an integer rounded value so it's better if you cast your numerator to double before division.

Comment: Edit your answer you can.

Answer (score 0):

The value of this `(z = 1)` is always 1, which is practically `true` (as any other non-zero value would also be).
That is why you always end up in the first option.

A solution would probably be to use `(z == 1)`.